# Как ожидать изменение переменной Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, циклы

Есть ли более эффективные способы ожидания изменения переменно помимо цикла `while !=...`, если у меня есть, скажем, другой поток, который я не могу дополнить кодом, и в нём меняет своё значение какая-то переменная N. Я, к примеру, хочу выполнить код, когда она будет равна 10.

```
while N != 10:
   pass
print("N=10")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого используются *condition variables*. В питоне это, например, `threading.Condition()`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.wait

Comment: Только это вряд ли поможет, ибо другой поток должен подтверждать Condition, а код этого потока, как указано в вопросе, ТС дополнить не может.